# Splitting strings without resulting in 2-D list

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

How do I split strings in a list without resulting in a 2-D list?

```
list1:['Ben&Jerry', 'Julia', 'Sally&Don', 'Tom', 'Tracy&Jim']
```

to output:

```
['Ben','Jerry','Julia','Sally', 'Don','Tom','Tracy','Jim']
```

using

```
flat_list=[s.split('&') if "&" in s else s for s in list1 ]
```

will give me a 2-D list.

Comment: `[i for s in list1 for i in s.split('&')]`. Checking if delimiter is present is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```py
[i for j in [i.split('&') for i in list1] for i in j]
```

Comment: See the comment by @Ch3steR for evidence that nesting a list comprehension in another is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Lazy way:

```
flat_list = '&'.join(list1).split('&')
```